# Is this coroutine really non-blocking while writing to a channel?

Tags: sqlite, tcl

I've been experimenting with trying to pass a blob to browser from a SQLite database without having to first write the blob to memory and not block the Tcl script. Evidently, `chan copy` with the `-command` would take care of this (I tried it with a file and it does not block) but this feature won't work with SQLite's `incrblob`.

I tried several ways to get around this and most were too far beyond my skill level and perhaps the wrong approach altogether. I was reading about coroutines again and saw an example that was using the Tcllib `coroutine:util` and wondered if I could do something similar without it.

The code below passes the blob, which is a 250 MB video file, to the browser as its `$sock` channel has a writable event. It works, in that the video plays and every 30 seconds or so, the event seems to fire and more data is copied.

I realize that the blob is ultimately still being copied to memory before being written to the out channel; but it is in small pieces based on the size passed in each `chan puts`.

My questions are:

1. Is this approach sound? It's in a minimal local server for a desktop application.
2. Is it really non-blocking now? It's rather difficult to test because the new requests from the browser are small and take a very short time to copy, such that there's no time to try to trigger another process at the same time. And that, in itself, is a solution to the blocking issue: just block for a very short interval that it is not noticeable. But, I'd like to know anyway. Both channels are set to `-blocking 0` and I think the coroutine is supposed to help it not block; but I don't fully understand that apart from the fact that it yields control back to the caller which, in this case, is a procedure with no remaining statements to execute. I take it that this means there is no need to use an `after 0 []` approach with the coroutine.
3. Does anyone know what the issue is with `incrblob`? Is it that its channel belongs to a different interpreter such that the events don't arrive at the right "place"?

Thank you for considering my question.

```
proc ::REQ::SendBLOB {sock filename type id} {
  dbws eval {select rowid, length(col_blob) as bytes from db.table where id=:id} {
    # Get the BLOB as a (read-only) channel
    set fp [dbws incrblob -readonly db table col_blob $rowid]
    chan configure $fp -translation binary -blocking 0
    chan configure $sock -translation binary -blocking 0
    # Would use chan copy with -command but it will not work with incrblob.
    # chan copy $fp $sock -size $bytes -command [list ::REQ::ChanCopyCleanup $fp]
  }
  coroutine ::coro_incrblob${sock} proxyfcopy $fp $sock $bytes
  chan event $sock writable ::coro_incrblob${sock}
}

proc proxyfcopy {fp sock bytes} {
  while { ![chan eof $fp] } {
    yield
    # Think this 4096 should be at least 5,120,000; for it appears
    # that Firefox requests 60 MB at first load and 5 MB thereafter.
    if { $bytes > 4096 } {
      set size 4096
    } elseif { $bytes > 0 } {
      set size $bytes
    } else {
      chan event $sock writable {}
      close $fp
      return
    }
    set data [read $fp $size]
    chan puts stdout $bytes
    chan puts -nonewline $sock $data
    set bytes [expr {$bytes - [string length $data]}]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `incrblob` channels don't support non-blocking operation; their underlying channel descriptor doesn't have the method to turn off blocking mode (that field in the C type record for the channel type is `NULL`). However, writes to the blob will be pretty fast anyway because they definitely don't involve reallocation of space — the incremental blob access mechanism can't change the size of the blob — or commit the transaction (in auto-commit mode, the commit happens when you close the channel; otherwise it happens when you `COMMIT` explicitly of course). It's a bit like dealing with a standard file; those *technically* allow you to set non-blocking mode but there's no point in doing so because the operating system actually ignores the flag in that situation (or rather it's more like all files are non-blocking, except if on a networked filesystem when you get blocked anyway because networked filesystems have weird semantics). For read-only `incrblob` channels, they're going to be effectively satisfied from memory once the DB has set things up and hence very very fast.

As you are also dealing with network sockets, *those* support non-blocking mode for real. In particular, sockets are writable when their OS-level output buffer is not full.

The `chan copy` implementation requires the read side to be non-blocking for async operation. You can't do that here, but you can still use synchronous `chan copy` to avoid copying data in the higher levels of the Tcl runtime. If you use fixed transfers with that (1444 is probably a good guess — that's a 1500 Ethernet MTU minus 54 bytes of overhead for Ethernet header, IP header and TCP header, rounded down to the size of a word — but larger might be fine too because you're ultimately dealing with a stream model when doing TCP and the OS does do some things for you; you'll need to measure) then you should get reasonable efficiency. Move one of those across whenever the output channel is writable.

Comment: There is nothing stopping @Gary from using synchronous `chan copy` in dedicated writer threads. (1) transfer the `incrblob` and `sock` channel to a thread (e.g. taken from a pool) using [`thread::transfer`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/ThreadCmd/thread.htm#M24) and (2) do the `chan copy` in that thread. Given the "reasonable efficiency" pointed out by Donal, a small pool of writer threads will suffice.

Comment: Thank you. When using synchronous `chan copy`, is the purpose of the fixed transfer size of 1444 bytes to "protect" against the browser filling its buffer at a partial transfer, leaving some bytes unwritten from the copy -size 1444 and resulting in Tcl blocking?  When experimenting with larger sizes, this took place at times; but, at 1444, I was not able to observe it taking place.

Comment: The 1444 was a guess at what would result in a packet being sent efficiently, with the guess being based on how much networking really works (which I'm unfortunately highly aware of). Larger values might also work fine; there's a lot of complexity in there. Using writable events to know when to do a copy mean that you will fill the OS and hardware network buffers but probably not block. These things definitely need tuning.